# Error while login site with ADFS using SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, adfs

I am able to login the site on the browser and I have full Site Collection Admin rights on that but When I opened SharePoint Designer and trying to open the site, it prompts a login pop-up window with one drop-down list (Windows Authentication & ADFS Staging).

[image]

[image]

I choose ADFS Staging because of policy but this message

> **"Sorry! This site hasn't been shared with you"**

appears after choose ADFS Staging from drop-downlist.

[image]